# Converting varchar array to array with jsonb objects

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have an array of strings, like this:

```
SELECT ARRAY['user1@example.com', 'user2@example.com', 'user3@example.com'];
```

How do I convert (map?) it into a jsonb array of jsonb objects like this?:

```
SELECT [{"email": "user1@example.com"}, {"email": "user2@example.com"}, {"email": "user3@example.com"}]::jsonb;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=12f04b80bd91b570f3f7f8e73a5d7d1d)

```
SELECT
    jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('email', elems))
FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY['user1@example.com', 'user2@example.com', 'user3@example.com'] AS a
) s,
unnest(a) AS elems
```

1. Expand the array elements into one record each with `unnest()`
2. Create the JSON objects using `jsonb_object_build()` to create the key/value structure your are expecting
3. re-aggregate these objects into one new JSON array using `jsonb_agg()`